# How to find a "direct" connected components?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I don't know graph theory, so I'm afraid question's title is not property formulated, so I will show a code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(igraph)

df <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 6),
                 to = c(2, 4, 3, 5, 3))

graph_from_data_frame(df) %>% 
  components() %>% 
  membership() %>% 
  stack()
#>   values ind
#> 1      1   1
#> 2      1   2
#> 3      1   6
#> 4      1   4
#> 5      1   3
#> 6      1   5


# find only "direct" paths

data.frame(values = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2),
           ind = c(1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5, 3))
#>   values ind
#> 1      1   1
#> 2      1   2
#> 3      2   6
#> 4      1   4
#> 5      1   3
#> 6      1   5
#> 7      2   3
```

Having a `data.frame` as above, I know how i can find all connected components, no matter "how" they are connected. But I would like also to be able to find something which is shown at the end of the code block above, i.e. that "6" do not belong to the group "1", but is connected with "3", that's why I have repeated "3" - it belongs to group "1" and "2".

Is there a function for this in `igraph` or other package in `R`? But I would prefer `igraph`. And does this procedure have a name in graph theory? So then I will be able to find some more information about this.

**EDIT**

Thank you all for help. I have found that for my use case I can use `igraph::subcomponent()` (I didn't find this function before at the bottom of `igraph::component()` help page), because at one time I need to find components only for one chosen vertex and I know if I need to find all components connected or just "simple paths" components and, luckily, in this second case it is always vertex "at the end" (beginning?) of path

```
df <- data.frame(react_id = c("r1", "r1", "r2", "r2", "r6"),
                 depends_on = c("r2", "r4", "r3", "r5", "r3"))

gdf <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(df)

# get all connected components for specific react_id

igraph::subcomponent(gdf, "r3", "all") |>
  names()
#> [1] "r3" "r2" "r6" "r1" "r5" "r4"

# get "simple paths" components

igraph::subcomponent(gdf, "r1", "out") |>
  names()
#> [1] "r1" "r2" "r4" "r3" "r5"
```

Comment: Great that you found the most effective solution with `subcomponent`. I think the only thing you need to do before running `subcomponent` should be identifying which vertices are the sources, i.e., indegree=0.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I need to take a look into this thing. In theory all vertex possible to choose in my case should be indegree=0, but before your comment I wasn't so aware about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(igraph)
)

df <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 6),
                 to = c(2, 4, 3, 5, 3))

g <- df |> graph_from_data_frame()
i <- g |> degree(mode = "out") > 0

lapply(V(g)[i], \(x) all_simple_paths(g, from = x, mode = "out"))
#> $`1`
#> $`1`[[1]]
#> + 2/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $`1`[[2]]
#> + 3/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`1`[[3]]
#> + 3/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 1 2 5
#> 
#> $`1`[[4]]
#> + 2/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 1 4
#> 
#> 
#> $`2`
#> $`2`[[1]]
#> + 2/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> $`2`[[2]]
#> + 2/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 2 5
#> 
#> 
#> $`6`
#> $`6`[[1]]
#> + 2/6 vertices, named, from c3ceef6:
#> [1] 6 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is thing you are after

```
lapply(
  V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0],
  function(x) V(g)[!is.infinite(distances(g, x, mode = "out"))]
)
```

which gives

```
$`1`
+ 5/6 vertices, named, from d7ae5cb:
[1] 1 2 4 3 5

$`6`
+ 2/6 vertices, named, from d7ae5cb:
[1] 6 3
```

---

If you want the result saved in a data.frame, you can try

```
transform(
  stack(
    lapply(
      V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0],
      function(x) names(V(g)[!is.infinite(distances(g, x, mode = "out"))])
    )
  ),
  ind = as.integer(factor(ind))
)
```

which gives

```
  values ind
1      1   1
2      2   1
3      4   1
4      3   1
5      5   1
6      6   2
7      3   2
```